# Should this question about passive Perception be closed as a duplicate of a closed question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicates, closing-questions

[Implementing Passive Wisdom (Perception)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/implementing-passive-wisdom-perception) was flagged as a potential duplicate of [How does passive perception work](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101169/how-does-passive-perception-work). The latter is a closed question, specifically flagged for being too broad and does not have an accepted answer.

Is this ok? Or should we only link to questions that are open and deemed 'acceptable' by the community?

It doesn't seem like the burden for opening a closed question should be on the querent.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to do here, but given that the question is exactly the same I put it as a duplicate. 

However, there is a good answer for it (Miatog is working on it, and i had one as well but didn't want to answer a duplicate, either) so maybe it should be looked at differently.

Comment: We could use a more descriptive title here.

Comment: I am certain this topic has been discussed on Meta before, ironically making _this_ a potential duplicate, but I can’t find it.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov perhaps, but it's been nearly 4 years and hasn't caused an issue without a more descriptive title, so I'm inclined to leave it be.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Sometimes you do things cuz it makes the place look nicer, not because it might cause an issue otherwise.

Comment: I've made an attempt at editing the title to be a bit more descriptive of what the post is about (which helps future users, e.g. those who encounter this post in search results, as I'm guessing Thomas did). Feel free to edit it to a ore appropriate title if you feel I've misidentified the intent of the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's a dupe, but the closed question isn't actually too broad.  In the case that a question is asked with clear effort/quality that is a dupe of a question seriously lacking in effort/quality, closing as a dupe the other direction (i.e. closing the older question as a dupe of the new one) is the preferable course of action.

In the case the older, much worse, question is closed, probably the thing to do is make a meta post or flag a moderator if it's really clear cut.  We can't make a dupe of an already closed question (viz. we can't have an already-closed question *also* be a duplicate of a new question, because posts can only have one close reason), so if we really want to have things closed in the ideal manner in that circumstance we might have to open the old question and then dupe it, or just delete it so there's no duplication. In the meantime the new question should be closed for whatever reason it needs closing (e.g. too broad in this case) so it's easier to see the real reason why it's closed instead of having to follow links.

Once the close reasons are dealt with, if it's still a dupe of the other question we can figure out what to do with it on meta.

Note that the existence closeworthy/uncloseworthy dupes of uncloseworthy/closeworthy (respectively) questions will always be a contentious issue when it crops up.  That's because being a dupe means that two questions are the same in terms of substance (i.e. the things that matter in terms of answering it), so their receiving differing treatment is/would be indicative of our community doing something it disagrees with, like treating questions/people differently based on how they talk or what background they come from in a question, or whether certain users asked or answered it.  That's not to say these situations don't come up, just that when they do and you go to post on meta about it you should be aware that the question about how to handle the duping will necessarily entail a discussion of why one of them ended up closed while the other didn't and if that's okay and what we think about it.